# Facing "com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections". java error while inserting"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
     String departurecity = depcity.getText();
        String depdate = dt.getText();
        String arrivalcity = ac.getText();
        String arrivaldate = dtar.getText();
        String cabinclass = ccc.getText();
        String seats = sts.getText();
        String price = prc.getText();

        try {
            Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:‪//localhost:8080/airblue", "root", "");
            java.sql.Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "INSERT INTO flight values('" + departurecity + "','" + depdate + "','" + arrivalcity + "','" +
                    arrivaldate + "','" +cabinclass + "','" + seats +"','"+price+ "')";

            Statement sta = (Statement) ((java.sql.Connection) connection).createStatement();
            int x = ((java.sql.Statement) sta).executeUpdate(query);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnNewButton,
                    "done");

            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a little part of my connection code ,I have tried many solutions but none of them worked for me any solution to this problem?

Comment: Try adding the stacktrace, as it will probably give a hint to the cause.

Comment: NOTE: Your SQL is a security hole and will get your server p0wned. Look up 'SQL injection'. Don't use createStatement. Only make preparedStatements.

Comment: @rzwitserloot using prepared statement without fixing the problem of string concatenation of values, wouldn't fix the problem though ;)

Comment: Did you copy that URL from somewhere? Clear it out and type it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your connection string, sometimes there might be a character after the semicolon in

```
mysql:‪//
```

Check your db url here and you will see for yourself: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php

Maybe type out that part by hand.